# Pandas How to convert from series to a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, series

suppose I have a simple Series like this data frame like this

```
S1 = Series([2.0, 0.816 , 0.2] , [51.0, 50.0 , 0.3])
```

What us the best way in pandas to convert this Series to a data frame like this

```
pd.DataFrame({
        'mean' :  [2.0 , 51.0] , 
        'median' : [0.816 , 50.0] , 
        'sd' : [0.2 ,0.3]
    })
```

this is how a data frame should look like

```
mean    median      sd
 2      0.816       0.2
 51     50.000      0.3
```

Comment: In the above series is `[51.0, 50.0 , 0.3]` the index? otherwise can you tell me how the series was created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### one method

You can do some index wizardry

```
D1 = S1.to_frame().reset_index().T
```

Now you can map the column names to whatever

```
D1.rename( columns={0:'mean',1:'median',2:'sd'}, inplace=True) # should match the list order in S1
D1.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True) # reset the funky index
#   mean  median   sd
#0    51  50.000  0.3
#1     2   0.816  0.2
```

### one more method

You can make a dictionary

```
vars     = ['mean','media','mode'] #again matching the order of the lists in S1
data_dict = dict(zip( vars,S1.iteritems()))
D1       = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict)
```